# what is the best approach in printing and previewing receipts in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, activereports, opos

I am building a park ticketing system and I am stuck on how to make the receipt for preview and can be printed on the printer. I searched on the internet and gave me lots of answers
now I am confuse which is better.

1. using crystal report
2. using active report
3. using pos.net
4. OPOS

I am new to this and I don't know what is the best approach for this.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion (any answer to this will be a matter of opinion) Crystal Reports is far and away the best option for this. I think it is the best option for program-ability and versatility. It integrates seamlessly into visual studio too.

If you are still unsure though, you could always read a little documentation on each and decide from there. My advice would be crystal though.

Comment: It will. I would love to see some proof otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

In order to create a report for receipt printing you can make use of [FPL](http://helpcentral.componentone.com/nethelp/AR7Help/OnlineEn/FPL.html) active reports.​ Using FPL, you can create report with [fixed designs](http://our.componentone.com/2012/04/18/introduction-to-activereports-developer-7/), suitable for ticketing systems.

ActiveReports also allows you to create and print reports with custom paper size. A similar issue has been discussed [here](http://www.datadynamics.com/forums/151811/ShowPost.aspx).

Regards,
Mohita